# Why is flask-socketio giving me a Bad request error?

Tags: flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am creating a bidding site and I currently want to implement a functionality that notifies a user when they have been outbid. I saw flask-socketIO and decided to use it. I am currently trying to establish a test connection but it is not working.

[Server output on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHUKY.png)

[Console output on the the flask server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TriP.png)

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connection():
    print('User has connected!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please try to add relevant log output to your question, rather than linking images.
The flask debug output indicates an error message - rephrasing your question, focusing on that message might make it easier to answer.

Comment: I will do so. Thanks for the input